# How to provide an implementation framework to a virtual method?

Tags: c++, design-patterns

For example, I have an abstract class with a virtual method

```
class A
{
public:
    virtual void setColumn(int i, string s); // set column i to show string s
    ...
};
```

The class is derived by some other abstract classes like `B` and `C`.

I find for most of objects of A follow the rule: it has 2 columns: name and description. To avoid repeating code (the real case is more complex, so I'd like to avoid the repeat), I add 2 more virtual methods in `A` because concretes classes have different implementations for `setName()` and `setDescription()`.

```
class A
{
public:
    virtual void setColumn(int i, string s)
    {
        if (i == 0)
            return setName(s);

        if (i == 1)
            return setDescription(s);
    }

    virtual void setName(string s);

    virtual void setDescription(string s);

    ...
};
```

Thus, users just need to re-implement `setName()` and `setDescription()` if the concrete class follow the rule. If not, they need to re-implement `setColumn()`. However, the 3 virtuals (`setName()` and `setDescription()` implement `setColumn()`) make me feel the design has some problem. Any good design for it?

Comment: are you wanting to make these methods pure virtual?

Comment: And what, in the end, is any of this supposed to accomplish?

Comment: @PaulNikonowicz No. The abstract means there are other pure virtual methods (not shown here).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any abstraction here.

Unless there are specific requirements, which would be pertinent to the question, just define a `public` container in the base  class.

```
struct A {
    std::vector< std::string > columns;

    enum columnIndex {
        name = 0,
        description = 1,
        numCols
    };

    A() : columns( numCols ) {}
};

A foo;
foo.columns[ A::name ] = "Fido";
```

Adding more boilerplate in C++ does not usually net you a safer, more maintainable program.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should cut this to two levels:

```
class IHasColumns
{
public:
    virtual void setColumn(int columnIndex, std::string value) =  0;
};

class IHasNameDescription : public IHasColumns
{
public:
    virtual void setName(std::string name) = 0;
    virtual void setDescription(std::string name) = 0;

private:
    // Override
    void setColumn(int columnIndex, std::string value)
    {
        if (i == 0)
            return setName(value);

        if (i == 1)
            return setDescription(value);
    }
};
```

Comment: Since `IHasColumns` (My `A`) have subclasses. Thus the `IHasNameDescription` will not implement those subclasses.